# Oracle After Update Trigger error

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to keep track of changes to one table in another table. What I need is an after update trigger which writes the name of changed column (if multiple columns are changed then there will be multiple inserts to the CHANGES table),the column's old and new values. How do I do that. I tried this but got an error after updating the table.So I'm giving you just the body.

```
IF :NEW.STAJYEAR!=:OLD.STAJYEAR THEN
 INSERT INTO X_STAJ (USERID,EDITDATE,CHANGEDCOLUMN,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE)
 VALUES (:NEW.USERID,SYSDATE,'STAJYEAR',:OLD.STAJYEAR,:NEW.STAJYEAR);
END IF;
```

the error code is :ORA-04098: trigger 'SYS.TR__TRACK_CHANGES' is invalid and failed re-validation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STAJCHANGER.TR_TRACK_CHANGES
AFTER UPDATE
OF STAJYEAR
  ,STAJMONTH
  ,STAJDAY
ON STAJCHANGER.STAJ 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
OLDVALUE NUMBER;
NEWVALUE NUMBER;
COLUMNID NUMBER;


BEGIN


   IF :NEW.STAJYEAR!=:OLD.STAJYEAR THEN
    INSERT INTO X_STAJ (USERID,EDITDATE,CHANGEDCOLUMN,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE)
    VALUES (:NEW.USERID,SYSDATE,'STAJYEAR',:OLD.STAJYEAR,:NEW.STAJYEAR);
    END IF;

   IF :NEW.STAJMONTH!=:OLD.STAJMONTH THEN
    INSERT INTO X_STAJ (USERID,EDITDATE,CHANGEDCOLUMN,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE)
    VALUES (:NEW.USERID,SYSDATE,'STAJMONTH',:OLD.STAJMONTH,:NEW.STAJMONTH);
    END IF; 

       IF :NEW.STAJDAY!=:OLD.STAJDAY THEN
    INSERT INTO X_STAJ (USERID,EDITDATE,CHANGEDCOLUMN,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE)
    VALUES (:NEW.USERID,SYSDATE,'STAJDAY',:OLD.STAJDAY,:NEW.STAJDAY);
    END IF;

END TR_TRACK_CHANGES;
/
```

Comment: You got an error?  Any clues as to what it said?

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?  And the table definitions, too?  Best guess at this point is the X_STAJ.OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE may not be type compatible with all the columns you want to record.

Comment: The error:ORA-04098: trigger 'SYS.TR__TRACK_CHANGES' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: @Mikayil can you post the complete trigger definition, then?

Comment: I edited my question and added the whole trigger code.

Comment: What happens when you try to compile the trigger. It should give you a different error and point you to what line has the problem. Also, does the table definition of X_STAJ have those 5 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL Plus command will show the error:

```
SHOW ERROR TRIGGER STAJCHANGER.TR_TRACK_CHANGES
```

Answer (score 4):

The error appears to indicates that the trigger owner is SYS, but the creation statement you show explicitly gives the owner as STAJCHANGER.

This makes me wonder, did you accidentally create an (invalid) version of the trigger in SYS at some point, and forget to drop it?